# Having trouble using Firebase storage + useEffect hook + useState hook to render images

Tags: reactjs, firebase, use-effect

Have searched up `useEffect` calling conventions, `async` and `await` usage, but for some reason I still cant get my code to work.

I have a list of image names stored in `data.recipeImgs`, and each name uses the formula of `data.id + i + ".pdf"`, where `i` is an index from 0 to length of `data.recipeImgs`. I simply wish to fetch every single image download url from firebase storage, and store those urls in a state variable so later on I can map each url to an `img` tag. What am I doing wrong? I keep printing out the value of the state variable `imgList` after each `.then`, and although I am getting the new image urls, the state variable never changes.

```
// image slideshow for recipe instructions
const [imgList, setImgList] = React.useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
        // function for firebase storage
        const getImg = async (i) => {
            var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();

            // Create a reference to the file we want to download
            var imgRef = storageRef.child(data.id + i + ".pdf");

            // Get the download URLs for each image
            await imgRef
                .getDownloadURL()
                .then((url) => {
                    console.log("got one ", imgList);

                    // append new image url to state var
                    setImgList([...imgList, url]);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        };

        // make sure data exists before trying to fetch all the images
        // from firebase storage
        if (data) {
            for (let i = 0; i < data.recipeImgs.length; i++) {
                getImg(i);
            }
        }
    }, [data]);

    // wait for data to finish loading
    if (!data) {
        return "Loading...";
    }
```

This is for a personal project, and any help would be appreciated, I'm sure I'm doing something stupid

**Edit**: added map function relevant code
Here is the code for the `myList` mapping:

```
                    <ui.Grid container>
                        <ui.Grid item xs={12}>
                            {imgList.map((url, ind) => {
                                <img src={url} alt="Recipe image" key={ind} />;
                            })}
                        </ui.Grid>
                    </ui.Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a functional update ([doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates))

```js
setImgList((imgList) => ([...imgList, url]));
```

What was happening here was that the `imgList` in the callback's scope was always the initial value `[]` and you override the state value with the latest url

```js
await imgRef
    .getDownloadURL()
    .then((url) => {
        // here imgList has always the initial value []
        setImgList([...imgList, url]);
    })
```

Comment: I tried this, and it still doesn't work. I am able to console log the `url` from the `.then` every single time, but for some reason the state variable still isn't changing.

Comment: Do you tried `setImgList((imgList) => ([...imgList, url]));` instead of `setImgList([...imgList, url])`?

In which point of the code are you printing the value os `imgList`?

Comment: I have replaced my `setImgList` with yours, and I `console.log(imgList)` immediately after doing that, yet it still says `imgList` is `[ ]`

Comment: The value of the `state` doesn't change immediatly after `setState`.
`setState` triggers a re-render of the component with an updated value of `state`.

You can try printing the value of `imgList` between the `useEffect` and the `if(!data)`

Comment: It printed! However, doesn't state change trigger a rerender of the page? For some reason, I have a `myList.map()` later on in the jsx that doesn't rerender. I will update my post with the appropriate code.

Comment: I fixed it, turns out I forgot the `return` in the `myList.map()`, thank you!

Comment: Great! BTW, 
1. If you use `await`, you don't need to `.then`, they are the same thing written in different ways, you can just `const url = await imageRef.getDownloadUrl()`
2. Be careful with asyncronous code, the urls in `imgList` may not be in ascending order, because one promise may resolve before the previous

Comment: thank you! i tried `await` because i couldnt figure out any other reason why my `imgList` wasnt updating

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230990/discussion-between-aaron-li-and-devid-farinelli).